# Create a new column based on a condition on multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have this dataset below:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(x_1 = c(3,2,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,3),
                 x_2 = c(2,1,1,3,2,3,3,1,2,3),
                 x_3 = c(2,3,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,1),
                 y_1 = sample(2, 10, replace = T),
                 y_2 = sample(2, 10, replace = T),
                 y_3 = sample(2, 10, replace = T))
```

I would like to perform an if else operation on the `x` columns and if any of the x columns is equal to 1, it would create a new column with the value of the corresponding y column. For e.g. in the 5th row, `x_3 = 1`, so the new column should return the value corresponding to y_3.

My idea was to return the name of the x column which matches the condition as an intermediate column and then use the value suffix (1,2,3) to extract the value from the corresponding y column.

But the 1st step to create the intermediate column is creating a list and the rows not matching the condition is returning `character(0)`.

```
cols <- c("x_1", "x_2", "x_3")
dt$int <- apply(dt[,..cols], 1, function(x) names(which(x == 1)))
```

My desired output:

```
x_1 x_2 x_3 y_1 y_2 y_3 new
3   2   2   1   2   2   NA
2   1   3   2   1   2   1
2   1   3   1   2   2   2
1   3   2   2   2   2   2
3   2   1   2   1   2   2
2   3   2   1   2   2   NA
1   3   3   2   1   2   2
2   1   3   2   1   2   1
3   2   1   2   1   1   1
3   3   1   1   2   1   1
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? A data-table based solution would be preferable.

Comment: what is your desired output for your sample dataset?

Comment: @chinsoon12 - Edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Is it ensured that there is only one  x column which is equal to 1 in each row? Or, what is the expected result if, e.g., both `x_1` and `x_3` are 1?

Comment: Your output is not consistent with the input. Maybe you somehow switched the order of a couple rows?

Comment: @Frank - Thanks for pointing that out. Edited the question to correct that.

Comment: @Uwe - Well luckily yes. Every row would have at most one x column which is equal to 1 and the toy data reflects that.

Comment: My actual data has NA values which is not reflected in the toy data and all of the below answers handle that perfectly!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you want to handle cases without any 1s or multiple ones in the x_* in the same row.

Here is a possible approach using `data.table::melt` into a long format, then find the first location 1 among the x_*, then access the y_* value

```
dt[, rn:=.I]
dt[melt(dt, id.vars="rn", meas=list(c("x_1", "x_2", "x_3"), c("y_1", "y_2", "y_3")))[,
    value2[which(value1==1L)[1L]], by=.(rn)], yval := V1, on=.(rn)]
```

output:

```
    x_1 x_2 x_3 y_1 y_2 y_3 rn yval
 1:   3   2   2   1   2   2  1   NA
 2:   2   1   3   2   1   2  2    1
 3:   2   1   3   1   2   2  3    2
 4:   1   3   2   2   2   2  4    2
 5:   3   2   1   2   1   2  5    2
 6:   2   3   2   1   2   2  6   NA
 7:   1   3   3   2   1   2  7    2
 8:   2   1   3   2   1   2  8    1
 9:   3   2   1   2   1   1  9    1
10:   3   3   1   1   2   1 10    1
```

---

edit: incorporating thelatemail's succinct version and also handling multiple ones as well

```
dt[, yval := 
    melt(dt, id.vars="rn", measure.vars=patterns("^x_", "^y_"))[value1==1L][
        dt, value2, on=.(rn), mult="first"]
]
```

Comment: Slight variation of the same concept - `dt[melt(dt, id.vars="rn", measure=patterns("x_", "y_"), value.name=c("x","y"))[x==1], on="rn", new := i.y]`

Comment: @thelatemail - Works perfectly for my data. I ended up using your suggestion as I used regex inside patterns to extract the variables in the actual data.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
ix <- dt[, max.col(.SD == 1) * NA^(!rowSums(.SD == 1)), .SDcols = 1:3]

dt[, newcol := as.matrix(.SD)[cbind(.I, ix)]
   , .SDcols = 4:6][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     x_1 x_2 x_3 y_1 y_2 y_3 newcol
>  1:   3   2   2   1   2   2     NA
>  2:   2   1   3   2   1   2      1
>  3:   2   1   3   1   2   2      2
>  4:   1   3   2   2   2   2      2
>  5:   3   2   1   2   1   2      2
>  6:   2   3   2   1   2   2     NA
>  7:   1   3   3   2   1   2      2
>  8:   2   1   3   2   1   2      1
>  9:   3   2   1   2   1   1      1
> 10:   3   3   1   1   2   1      1
> ```

***Notes:***

- Instead of `as.matrix` you can also use `as.data.frame`.
- If you have more than one x column which is equal to 1, then you need to use the `ties.method`-parameter of `max.col`. You can choose between `"random"`, `"first"` or `"last"`.

---

If you don't know the column positions beforehand, you can generalize the above solution to:

```
xcols <- like(names(dt), "x")
ycols <- like(names(dt), "y")

ix <- dt[, max.col(.SD == 1) * NA^(!rowSums(.SD == 1)), .SDcols = xcols]

dt[, newcol := as.matrix(.SD)[cbind(.I, ix)]
   , .SDcols = ycols][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `Map`. Subset the subset of data.table (`.SD`) for the 'x' and 'y' columns, create a logical vector of the 'x' columns and get the corresponding 'y' value where 'x' is 1, and collapse it to a single element with `pmin` (assuming that 'x columns do not have more than 1 per each row)

```
dt[, new := do.call(pmin, c(Map(function(x, y) y * NA^(x != 1),
      .SD[, 1:3, with = FALSE], .SD[, 4:6, with = FALSE]), na.rm = TRUE)), ]
dt
#    x_1 x_2 x_3 y_1 y_2 y_3 new
# 1:   3   2   2   1   2   2  NA
# 2:   2   1   3   2   1   2   1
# 3:   2   1   3   1   2   2   2
# 4:   1   3   2   2   2   2   2
# 5:   3   2   1   2   1   2   2
# 6:   2   3   2   1   2   2  NA
# 7:   1   3   3   2   1   2   2
# 8:   2   1   3   2   1   2   1
# 9:   3   2   1   2   1   1   1
#10:   3   3   1   1   2   1   1
```